# How to choose template while iterating in <thead/>?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table

I have an array:

```
let headers = [
    { title: 'First Name', style: 'bold' },
    { title: 'Last Name', style: 'bold' },            
    { title: 'Book', style: 'bold', titleSecond: 'All/Remainder', style2:'not bold' },
    { title: 'City', style: 'not bold', titleSecond: 'Street', style2: 'not bold' }
    ];
```

and I am iterating through simple HTML table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let header headers">
                {{ header.title }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Is it possible to make the table header that looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to create some templates for table header? I can alter my object as I want to alter this `headers` object.

Comment: What is the problem with it? Why does your forth object have duplicate property `style`?

Comment: @yurzui oops, sorry, I've edited an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally change to bold by using ***ngIf**

```
<th *ngFor="let header headers">
 <span *ngIf="header.style==='bold'"> <b>{{ header.title }}<b></span>
<span *ngIf="header.style!='bold'"> {{ header.title }}
```

```
<br> {{header.titleSecond}}
</th>
```

If you want to make this particular logic in to reusable component , you have to create a child component and pass **header** to the child component. From the child component you will get the value with **@Input**

```
 <th *ngFor="let header headers">
     <your-childcomponent [header]="header"></your-childcomponent>
    </th>
```

**Child Component**

```
     import { Component, Input,  } from '@angular/core';
@Component({

    selector: 'your-childcomponent',
    templateUrl: "YourChildComponent.html"
})
        export class YourChildComponent {
            @Input() header:any;

        }
```

**YourChildComponent.html**

```
<span *ngIf="header.style==='bold'"> <b>{{ header.title }}<b></span>
    <span *ngIf="header.style!='bold'"> {{ header.title }}</span>
<br> {{header.titleSecond}}
```

I hope this you are expecting

Comment: @Yatinpatel Thank You..My mistake

Comment: Thanks! What about `Book <br> All/Remainder` header?

Comment: @StepUp  I hope you have no logic for titleSecond. So You can directly place after the span. It's applicable in both bold and not bold scenario

Comment: @StepUp Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! But this piece of code is always bold: `<span *ngIf="header.style!='bold'"> {{ header.title }}</span>`.

Comment: No, condition works, there is data in <tr/>, but data is always bold. I want not bold text in header.

Comment: @StepUp then I would suggest create a child component same as like in my answer. instead of passing header as input parameter pass the value that you want to apply condition. So you can reuse this component in both tr and th